# Convert FFFFFF to decimal value (C language)

Tags: c

I am trying to convert a string representing a 24-bit hexadecimal number (FFFFFF) to its decimal equivalent (-1). Could anyone help me understand why the following code does not return -1?

Thanks, LC

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
char temp_str[] = "FFFFFF";
long value;
value = strtol(temp_str, NULL, 16);
printf("value is %ld\n", value);
}
```

Comment: It is converting `FFFFFF` to `16777215` which is correct. What's the problem?

Comment: Why sould `0xffffff` by equivalent to `-1` is converting to at least 32bits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your input is the 24-bit 2's complement representation of the number, but `strtol` does not handle negative numbers in this way (and even if it did, it has no way of knowing that you meant a 24-bit representation). It only determines the sign of its output based on the existence of a `-` sign.

You can modify your code to get the result you want by adding this after the `strtol`:

```
if (value > 0x7fffff)
    value -= 0x1000000;
```

Of course, this will only work for a 24-bit representation, other sizes will need different constants.

Comment: I don't know your solution is correct or not but `value = (value << 8) >> 8` is easier to understand

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc My solution is portable, while yours will only work with 32-bit `long`s, and even then it will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: A hacker's delight solution is `value = (value ^ 0x800000) - 0x800000;` which is portable and is better for pipelining. Posted in my answer. Also, you should be subtracting 0x800000, not 0x1000000...

Comment: @nonsensickle 0x1000000 is the correct value to subtract. `0xffffff - 0x1000000 == -1`.

Comment: Hmm, true, my mistake. It's late here.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Hacker's delight covers this under [sign extension](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/information-technology-and-software-development/0201914654/basics/ch02lev1sec5).

For your 24 bit number, the *sign* bit is the 24th bit from the right and if it was set the hex value would be `0x800000`.

The book suggests these:

```
((x + 0x800000) & 0xFFFFFF) - 0x800000

or

((x & 0xFFFFFF) xor 0x800000) - 0x800000
```

From your question I would say that your number is never going to be more than 24 bits so I would use the second option in your code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char temp_str[] = "FFFFFF";
    long value;
    value = strtol(temp_str, NULL, 16);
    value = (value ^ 0x800000) - 0x800000; // Notice that I'm not using the & 0xFFFFFF since I assumed that the number won't have more than 24 bits.
    printf("value is %ld\n", value);
}
```

**Edit 1:**

I fear that my original answer, though technically sound did not answer the posed question.

> Could anyone help me understand why the following code does not return -1?

Others have already covered this by the time I answered but I will restate it here anyway.

Your string is `"FFFFFF"`, it consists of 6 hex digits. Each hex digit represents 4 bits, therefore your string represents a 24 bit number.

Your variable `long value` is of type **long** which normally corresponds to your CPU's word width (32bit or 64bit). Since these days `long` can be either 32 bits or 64 bits depending on your architecture you are not guaranteed to get `-1` unless you give exactly the right number of hex digits.

If `long` on your machine is 32 bits then two things are true:

1. `sizeof(long)` will return 4
2. Using `"FFFFFFFF"` will return -1

If `long` on your machine is 64 bits then two things are true:

1. `sizeof(long)` will return 8
2. Using `"FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"` will return -1

**Digression**

This then lead me down a completely different path. We can generalize this and make a program that constructs a string for your machine, such that it will always return -1 from a string.

```
#include #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    const char* ff = "FF";
    char temp[sizeof(long) * 2 + 1]; // Ensure that the string can store enough hex digits so that we can populate the entire width of long. Include 1 byte for '\0'
    int i;
    long value;

    /* Fill the temp array with FF */
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(long); ++i)
    {
        strcpy(&temp[i * 2], ff);
    }

    value = strtol(temp, NULL, 16);
    printf("value of %s is %ld\n", temp, value);
}
```

This is a bad way to get a -1 result since the clear option is to just use

```
long value = -1;
```

but I will assume that this was simply an academic exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think as a computer now, just convery (FFFFFF)16 to decimal use ordinary math thinking. This is not about two's complement negative notation.

Answer (score 0):

Because you run this program on 32- or 64-bit machine, not 24-bit. 0xffffff is actually 0x00ffffff, which is 16777215 in decimal.

Hex representation of -1 is 0xffffffff or 0xffffffffffffffff.

Comment: This is actually not the problem. Even if you ran it with `"FFFFFFFF"` on a 32-bit machine it would not return -1, but `LONG_MAX`.

Comment: Well, he can always use strtoul() and convert unsigned long to long.

Comment: Note: It's not the size of `int` (32- or 64-bit machine), but of `long`.  A typical 16-bit machine would use a 32-bit long and have similar issues.